# Shell scripting trying to launch tasks in parallel?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

The basic task I need to do is call a python script multiple times, each time with a different argument. For example:

```
script.py -t command1
script.py -t command2
script.py -t command3
```

Etc. Now the problem is that script.py takes a long time to run, so just putting the above in a shell script and running them in series (one after another) is a waste of time.

Instead what I'd like to be able to do is open up multiple terminals, and in each one, run

```
script.py -t command_i
```

For the ith command argument. Is there any way of doing this? If not, are there any other helpful parallel options for what I'm trying to do?

Cheers

EDIT - just realized: I probably want some sort of forking, yes? I've never done that with shell scripting though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a command in the background, add an `&` at the end:

```
script.py -t command1 &
script.py -t command2 &
script.py -t command3 &
```

If you are using this in a shell script and want to wait for all the processes to finish, run `wait` without arguments. It will wait for all background jobs in the current shell to complete before continuing the script.

Comment: You should provide an explanation with your solution.

Comment: @YoungMoney - Emil Vikström is absolutely correct.  All you need to do to "fork" is put an ampersand ("&") in your command.

Comment: It is worth adding a `wait` afterwards in case someone decides to wrap those background jobs in a script, so it does not terminate immediately giving a false impression.